# Question about abelian covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm working on exercise 1.3.19 of Hatcher's book, more specifically in first part of the problem

> Use the preceding problem to show that a closed orientable surface $M_g$ of genus $g$ has a connected normal covering space with deck transformation group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ iff $n \leq 2 g$.

**My attempt**

So, let $p:\tilde{X}\to M_g$ be an abelian covering space such that the group of deck transformation $G(\tilde{X}) = \pi(M_g)/p_*(\pi(\tilde{X}))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$. We know that

$$
\pi(M_g) = \langle a_1,b_1,\cdots, a_g,b_g| \left[a_1,b_1\right] \cdots \left[a_g,b_g\right] \rangle
$$

and $(\pi(M_g))^{ab} = \mathbb{Z}^{2 g}$ is the universal abelian covering of $M_g$. Observe that $N =p_*(\pi(\tilde{X})) \lhd \pi(M_g)$, $ A = \left[ \pi(M_g), \pi(M_g)\right]  \lhd \pi(M_g)$ and $A$ is the smaller normal subgroup of $\pi(M_g)$ such that $\pi(M_g)/A$ is abelian, therefore, since $\pi(M_g)/N$ is abelian, we have $A \subset N$. By the third isomorphism theorem, there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between the normal subgroup of $\pi(M_g)$ and $\pi(M_g)/A$, futhemore $N$ is a normal contanning $A$ iff $N/A \lhd \pi(M_g)/A$, then
$$
\frac{\pi(M_g)/A}{N/A} \cong \frac{\pi(M_g)}{N}\cong \mathbb{Z}^n
$$

But how can I conclude that $n \leq 2g$? I think that its follows from the fact that, if $q:\tilde{A} \to X$ is the universal abelian covering of $X$, then $q:\tilde{A} \to \tilde{X}$ is a covering space of $\tilde{X}$, futhemore, $\mathbb{Z}^n \leqslant \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ iff $n\leq 2g$ but I cannot conlude not from this. There is some relation between the abeilan universal covering, the deck transformation of $G(\tilde{A})$ and $G(\tilde{X})$? I'm confused about the reciprocal, could someone help me?

Comment: Iirc Hatcher does not even define genus at this point

Comment: how not?  what are you talking about?

Comment: Hint: a surjection $\pi(M_g) \to \mathbb{Z}^n$ factors through $\pi(M_g)^{\text{ab}} \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ and hence the induced map is a surjection $\mathbb{Z}^{2g} \to \mathbb{Z}^n.

Comment: @FShrike You can certainly define what the "(oriented) surface of genus $g$" is without defining the genus of a general (oriented) surface. Not sure what the relevance of your comment is.